# Multiplication of 2 6-digits numbers in java

Tags: java

Why does the output of the following code output 1345094336 instead of 39999800000? And how should i edit it? I believe it has got to do with integer overflow.

```
public class testC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long product = 199999 * 200000;
        System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `long product = 199999 * 200000L;` otherwise it is multiplying using int values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplication of two ints 199999 * 200000 is 39999800000 which is over than the integer

```
storage capacity.
          width                     minimum                         maximum

SIGNED
byte:     8 bit                        -128                            +127
short:   16 bit                     -32 768                         +32 767
int:     32 bit              -2 147 483 648                  +2 147 483 647
long:    64 bit  -9 223 372 036 854 775 808      +9 223 372 036 854 775 807

UNSIGNED
char     16 bit                           0                         +65 535
```

So you need to convert at least one number to long on the multiplication side
Either

```
(long)199999 * 200000
199999 * (long)200000
199999 * 200000L
199999L * 200000
```

Comment: This is very thorough.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers getting multiplied are presumed to be ints, and so that overflows, and setting it to long does not help.Use

```
long product = (long)199999 * (long)200000;
```

instead

Answer (score 2):

You can change below line

`long product = 199999 * 200000;`

to

`long product = 199999 * 200000L;`

Since multiple of two integers is an integer and it overflows in this case, you have to make one of them a long.

Comment: You have to make *one* of them a `long`.